# Ckeditor HTML div's replaced with p tag automatically on save

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to use ck editor , I add html to editor box it saved to database successfully. When i reopen my editor page and check source it vanish my all div's and all p tag to all html can you please help me how i can get out from this problem.

Comment: Do you load saved content from your database to editor again during reopening page?

Comment: yes that why it cause this problem

Comment: I am loading data from databse that why its causing problem I saved html to database first it works fine .But when i slect db data to show in ckeditor textbox thus it cause problem you caught my problem thasnk  @MateuszSamsel Please suggest me what i can do for this

Comment: can we execute php tag in ckeditor ?

Comment: If you provide `<textarea>` tag which later on is replaced as editor. You can simply populate `<textarea>` with data. I'm not sure if inner tags should be escaped or not, but you can try both ways.
`<textarea><p>Hello world</p></textarea>`

Comment: I use this for textarea using editor

<?php echo $this->ckeditor->editor("content", htmlspecialchars($page[0]['content'])); ?>

Comment: I'm not an expert with php, so I don't know what kind of content it will generate in HTML. Just create better description of your question, to understand what exactly happen there and what have you tried already.

Comment: I looked with fresh eye on your question. If your problem is that DIV are replaced with P, take a look on this example: https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.8.0/full-all/samples/old/enterkey/enterkey.html
You can manipulate with configuration how new paragraphs are created with enterMode.

Comment: Ok Thanks @MateuszSamsel